# Youtube iframe video using php

Tags: php, mysql, iframe, youtube

I am trying to display a youtube embedded video using code stored in database. But its showing an error.what am i doing wrong..?

```
  <?php
    require 'db.php';
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM ycodes") or die($mysqli->error());
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    echo $row['ycode'];
    ?>


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?$row['ycode']?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    </body>
    </html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?$row['ycode']?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**Change To**

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $row['ycode'];?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```